# How to paginate chat fetched from firestore while scrolling to the top while also adding a listener

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to swift and I successfully managed to build a chat app by watching tutorials. Right now, when I click on a user, it takes me to the chat controller and it is successfully able to fetch messages. Everything works fine. What I need to implement is to be able to paginate chat as I scroll to the top. Right now I am fetching all the messages every time the chat room is opened.

I did check out the google firestore docs on how to do this, but for the life of me I am not able to piece it together. Have a fair idea on how it works theoretically. But since I have snapshot listeners added, it is a bit confusing.

Also have no clue how to configure the scrollView to load when it reaches the top

```
class ChatLogController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

//MARK: Initialize

fileprivate let connect: Connect
var listener: ListenerRegistration?
var currentUser: User?

init(connect: Connect){
    self.connect = connect
    super.init()
}   

//MARK: ****View Did Load****

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchCurrentUser()
    fetchPaginatedMessages()
    setupView()
}

//MARK: Fetch Current User

fileprivate func fetchCurrentUser(){
       //Some code  
        print("Current User Fetched Successfully")
        self.currentUser = User(dictionary: data)
    }
}

//MARK: Setup View
//Some code that fetches the front end


//MARK: FetchPaginatedMessages - Code does not contain attempted pagination

fileprivate func fetchPaginatedMessages(){

    print("Fetching Messages")
    guard let cUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}

    let query = Firestore.firestore().collection("matches").document(cUid).collection(connect.uid).order(by: "Timestamp")

    listener = query.addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let error = error{
            print("There was an error fetching messages", error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        querySnapshot?.documentChanges.forEach({ (change) in
            if change.type == .added{
                let dictionary = change.document.data()
                self.items.append(.init(dictionary: dictionary))
                print("ARCHID ---- FIRESTORE HAS BEEN CONTACTED FETCHING MESSAGES")
            }
        })

        self.collectionView.reloadData()

        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: [0, self.items.count - 1], at: .bottom, animated: true)
        print("Fetched messages")
    }
}
```

Included the main parts of the code. Omitted irrelevant code for ease of read. func fetchPaginatedMessages is where I aim to do the pagination.

Comment: Pagination is Firestore can be done by using .startAt and/or .endAt (Query Cursors). There's some really good documentation in the Getting Started Guide [Paginate data with query cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors). You can also pass a document snapshot to the cursor to define the start or end point of the query cursor. I am not seeing where you are actually doing Firestore pagination in your code - perhaps I am overlooking it or misunderstanding what you're asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: Oh... and the Ray Wenderlich Tutorial is a MUST read. [UITableView Infinite Scrolling Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5786-uitableview-infinite-scrolling-tutorial) if you want to understand infinite scrolling.

Comment: Hi Jay thanks for your comment. I am actually not doing any pagination. I have just named the function as such to indicate that it's meant to do pagination. Yes I did read the article in the link before I posted on stackoverflow but I am not able to wrap my head around how it works especially when I am using listeners

Comment: Hmm. Your question is *How to paginate* meaning that you are asking how to paginate.... but your not doing pagination? Meaning you do not want to do pagination or you do not know *how* to implement the code?

Comment: @Jay I meant that I tried to execute the code in firebase docs but was not able to get it to work. Plus I am not able to understand how the pagination is meant to be triggered when I am at the top of the scroll. So i ended up just posting how I am receiving all the messages and how I can convert this to pagination.

Comment: We are not a code writing service and will generally not write the code for you but are happy to try to help with existing code you're having problems with. Please update your question with the code you've attempted to make work. You should also include a snippet of your Firebase structure so we can understand what data you're loading in and trying to paginate.

Answer (score 0):

I myself struggled for pagination for a long time as everyone is loading more when user reaches to bottom which is pretty easy and you can find the solution on stackoverflow, but no one implemented the load previous thing (mean when user scrolls to top and do pull to refresh for older messages cuz in chat you have to show latest messages first and then older one and your scrolling also goes backward as latest messages is at bottom and oldest is at top).
After so much struggle i found this solution which is working perfectly fine.

First of all you are implementing snapshot listener which will give you all the messages in that table (document). You have to change it a bit. Ignore all data for very first time you enter your chat screen (i know it looks stupid but it works). Cuz snapshot listener is required for new messages otherwise you don't get the latest messages.

Then do your pagination on the document. Here is my solution field names can be vary.

Plus i am using MessageKit for showing chat UI you can change accordingly.
Here goes my chat view controller for pagination you can change according to your requirement.
My code pull older messages when user trigger pull to refresh not automatically you can find the code for infinite scrolling to top for your requirement.
Thanks.

```
class ChatViewController1: MessagesViewController {

    // MARK: - Variables -
    var messages: [Message] = []
    var pageSize: Int = 25
    var handles: [ListenerRegistration] = []
    var lastSnapShot: QueryDocumentSnapshot?
    var msgNode = "Your Table Name"
    
    private(set) lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
        let control = UIRefreshControl()
        control.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loadMoreMessages), for: .valueChanged)
        return control
    }()
    
    // MARK: - Life Cycle -
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        messagesCollectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
        self.setupChat()
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        
        for item in handles {
            
            item.remove()
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Setup Methods -
    @objc func loadMoreMessages() {
        self.getChat(lastSnapShot)
    }
    
    func setupChat() {
        FIRDBManager.shared.db
            .collection(self.msgNode)
            .order(by: "messageTime", descending: false).addSnapshotListener(includeMetadataChanges: true) { snapshot, error in
                if let error = error{
                    print("There was an error fetching messages", error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                // I am checking if messages already exist then it means this is new message or earlier message updated / deleted so handle it that way.
                if self.messages.count > 0 {
                    snapshot?.documentChanges.forEach({ (change) in
                        let dictionary = change.document.data()
                        
                        let msg = Message(fromDictionary: dictionary)
                        
                        if change.type == .added {
                            if !self.messages.contains(msg) {
                                self.messages.append(msg)
                            }
                        } else if change.type == .removed {
                            self.messages.removeAll(where: { $0.messageId == msg.messageId })
                        } else if let index = self.messages.firstIndex(of: msg) {
                            
                            self.messages[index] = msg
                        }
                    })
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.messagesCollectionView.reloadData()
                        self.messagesCollectionView.scrollToLastItem()
                    }
                }
            }
        
        self.getChat(nil)
    }
    
    func getChat(_ snap: QueryDocumentSnapshot?) {
        
        let query: Query
        
        if let _ = snap {
            query = FIRDBManager.shared.db
                .collection(self.msgNode)
                .order(by: "messageTime", descending: false)
                .end(at: [messages.first!.messageTime!])
                .limit(toLast: self.pageSize)
            
            //end(atDocument: s)
        } else {
            query = FIRDBManager.shared.db
                .collection(self.msgNode)
                .order(by: "messageTime", descending: false)
                .limit(toLast: self.pageSize)
        }
        
        query.getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
            if let e = err {
                print("Error fetching document: \(e.localizedDescription)")
                self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            } else if snapshot!.isEmpty {
                print("Document is empty")
                self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            } else {
                self.updateMessages(snapshot!)
            }
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate func updateMessages(_ snapshot: QuerySnapshot) {
        if snapshot.documents.count <= 1 {
            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            return
        }
        var allMessages: [Message] = []
        
        snapshot.documents.forEach { (item) in
            if item.documentID != "DeviceIds" {
                let msg = Message(fromDictionary: item.data())
                allMessages.append(msg)
            }
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.messages.count > 0 {
                self.messages.insert(contentsOf: allMessages, at: 0)
                self.messagesCollectionView.reloadDataAndKeepOffset()
                self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            } else {
                self.messages = allMessages
                self.messagesCollectionView.reloadData()
                self.messagesCollectionView.scrollToLastItem()
            }
            self.lastSnapShot = snapshot.documents.last
        }
    }
}
```